# How to evaluate this definite integral in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

I am a beginner in *Mathematica*. I tried to evaluate this integral, but was unable to do so. Can anybody help me evaluate this integral in *Mathematica*? Here is my integral:
$$\int_{a}^{b}  \frac{dx}{G(x)}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\Big{[}\frac{1+x}{n-x}\Big{]}e^{-\beta E_{n}(x)}$$ where $G(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-\beta E_{n}(x)}$ and $E_{n}(x)=-nx$ and $\beta$ is a constant.

Comment: Can you provide the code you used?

Comment: Do you know how to sum a geometric series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited to correct error noted by [José Antonio Díaz Navas](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1309/jos%C3%A9-antonio-d%C3%ADaz-navas) in the comment below.**

As noted by [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m), the series can be summed explicitly.

```
g = Sum[Exp[β n x], {n, 0, Infinity}]
(* -(1/(-1 + E^(x β))) *)
h = Sum[Exp[β n x] (1 + x)/(n - x), {n, 0, Infinity}]
(* HurwitzLerchPhi[E^(x β), 1, -x] + x HurwitzLerchPhi[E^(x β), 1, -x] *)
```

Repeating these summations with `GenerateConditions -> True` indicates that `E^Re[x β] < 1` is needed for convergence.  In addition, it is necessary to avoid integer values of `x`, as can be seen from

```
Plot[Evaluate[(h/g) /. β -> -1], {x, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {-3, 1}, PlotPoints -> 1000, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Even with these constraints, attempting to solve the integral by, for instance,

```
Integrate[h/g, {x, a, b}, Assumptions -> β a < 0 && β b < 0 && 1 < x < 2]
```

returns unevaluated.  To make progress, choose values for the constants and use `NIntegrate`.  For instance,

```
NIntegrate[h/g /. β -> -1, {x, 1.0001, 1.9999}]
(* -4.96337 *)
```

Comment: Is not the integrand $h/g$ ?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas indeed it is. And perhaps even if the two series are divergent, maybe their ratio is finite?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas  Thanks you for identifying my error, which I have corrected.